# Springboot locale with Rest request and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

So another application directs user to my server. The redirect is Post request (`application/json`) with value `language` in the JSON. How should I set the locale value in RestController? So that Thymeleaf could render the correct text.

Setting locale with `LocaleContextHolder` doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with the following solution:

`WebMvcConfigurer` has these

```
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver r = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        r.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("jp"));
        return r;
    }
```

And in the controller I call this classes public method:

```
@Component
public class WebLanguage {
    public void setLocale(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (!request.getParameterMap().containsKey("lang")) return;

        LocaleResolver localeResolver = localeResolver(request);
        localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale(request.getParameterMap().get("lang")[0]));
    }

    LocaleResolver localeResolver(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this guide [here](https://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/13/part-4-internationalization-in-spring-boot/) since Internationalization is a common task in spring-boot. In case if you need a short answer:

First configure a `LocaleResolver` in your **Application.java**:

```
@Bean(name = "localeResolver")
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
  SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
  slr.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("tr", "TR"));
  return slr;
}
```

Then again in your **Application.java** file configure a LocaleChangeInterceptor:

```
@Bean(name = "localeChangeInterceptor")
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
  LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
  lci.setParamName("lang");
  return lci;
}
```

And finally register your **LocaleChangeInterceptor** (also in Application.java):

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
  registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

Now if you send a ***request parameter*** named **"lang"** with your POST request spring will use its value to determine the desired locale and change it accordingly.

Comment: Yeah with this solution, it's taking the language from URL parameter not from JSON.